# Problem with the font size of LaTeX in a bookdown

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, bookdown

I'm looking for documentation to fix the problem: The default size of the latex in the bookdown appears very small to me.
I have tried to put;

```
  /* Increase size of mathjax formulas */
.mathjax {
   font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

to the style.css file but does not modify it.

I currently use r studio from anaconda navigator

[image: Problem]

[image: Apparent solution]

But I want to put it on a web page and the user will see the fine print by default.
Thank you so much.